# VBA in Access Loop function is looping based on wrong table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two tables, one (DATES) is a list of 25 dates. The second (RatingsBackDated) is a list of 13,000 names, ratings, IDs and dates. I am trying to create a loop function that goes through and appends the last rating nearest to a date to a table (tblCoDtRtgs). Currently, my code goes through and returns the data from 25 fields, correctly returning the nearest/last data from each of the 25 dates in table DATES. I need it to provide the information for all 13,000. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!
-J.

```
   Public Function PopulateTableOfRatingHistory()

  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  Dim dtDate As Date 'snapshot date
  Dim sqlAppend As String

   Dim sqlQueryLastRating As String


   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
   Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
   Set rs1 = dbs.OpenRecordset("DATES") 'check this to make sure it imports the table values

    rs1.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs1.EOF
        'get the date value to use as a parameter
        dtDate = rs1.Fields(1).Value ' get the date value to lookup

        'use the date parameter to run the SQL for the last rating as of the given date
        sqlQueryLastRating = "SELECT RatingsBackDated.name, RatingsBackDated.CoID, Last(RatingsBackDated.Rating) AS LastOfRating, Last(RatingsBackDated.Date) AS LastOfDate " & _
            "FROM RatingsBackDated " & _
            "WHERE (((RatingsBackDated.Date)<= #" & dtDate & "#)) " & _
            "GROUP BY RatingsBackDated.name, RatingsBackDated.CoID;"

        Debug.Print sqlQueryLastRating
        Set rs2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlQueryLastRating)

        'append the query result to a table
        sqlAppend = "INSERT INTO tblCoDtRtgs ( CoID, SnapDate, Rating, RatingDate ) VALUES (" & rs2.Fields(1) & ", #" & dtDate & "#, " & rs2.Fields(2) & ", #" & rs2.Fields(3) & "#);"

        dbs.Execute sqlAppend

        rs2.Close

    rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

  End Function
```

Comment: Would make more sense if you included sample data with sample output. It looks like it's doing what you want it to do - but then we don't know what you're trying to get out of each of the 13000 lines

Comment: Did you try to debug.Print the result of rs2 after opening?

Comment: Should be able to accomplish with a query. Provide samples as already suggested.